# Getting FPS and frame-time info from a GPU

Tags: directx, nvidia, vulkan, frame-rate, amd-gpu

I am a mathematician and not a programmer, I have a notion on the basics of programming and am a quite advanced power-user both in linux and windows.
I know some C and some python but nothing much.

I would like to make an overlay so that when I start a game it can get info about AMD and Nvidia GPUs like frame time and FPS because I am quite certain the current system benchmarks used to compare two GPUs is flawed because small instances and scenes that bump up the FPS momentarily (but are totally irrelevant in terms of user experience) result in a higher average FPS number and mislead the market either unintentionally or intentionally. For example, I cant remember the name of the game probably COD there was a highly tessellated entity on the map that wasn't even visible to the player which lead AMD GPUs to seemingly under perform when roaming through that area leading to lower average FPS count.

I have an idea on how to calculate GPU performance in theory but I don't know how to harvest the data from the GPU. Could you refer me to API manuals or references to help me making such an overlay possible?

I would like to study as little as possible (by that I mean I would like to learn what I absolutely have to learn in order to get the job done I don't intent to become a coder).

I thank you in advance.

Comment: Similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60661215/is-there-a-programmatic-way-to-see-what-graphics-api-a-game-is-using. You might want to fork something like [OCAT](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/OCAT), and do your thing within it.

Comment: That is useful and I didnt think about that the overlay should first determine the API a game uses I suppose to harvest the data I need but its not the same question I would like to know how to get FPS, and frame-time info (I suppose frame-time info alone would suffice but since we are dealing with high time resolution maybe FPS would be handy as well ) .

Comment: Well, no, the question is slightly different, but the underlying problem is the same: you want to intercept arbitrary application's presentation calls and make your overlay. The tool I link supports both DirectX and Vulkan, so hopefully for the most part they handle the differences for you. When you intercept presents, that means you have frame times. If you have frame time you are able to aggregate them into FPS (if you meant per literal second, not just inverted frame time), or any other way you wish.

Comment: Minus the overlay you want, you might also want [PresentMon](https://github.com/GameTechDev/PresentMon), which can output present times to CSV(as well as other interesting info). PS: I probably misunderstood what you meant by "overlay" (by overlay I understand something that draws over the original e.g. the Steam overlay), so this tool may be what you want. Want me to make this the answer?

Comment: @papajo: "*small instances and scenes that bump up the FPS momentarily (but are totally irrelevant in terms of user experience) result in a higher average FPS number*" That's how averages *work*. So, do you have a problem with statistics? And how relevant this is to user experience depends on the person. Personally, I prefer *consistency* in my framerate; I'd rather have a solid 30fps than 60fps mostly but 20fps every second or two.

Comment: @NicolBolas I dont have a problem in statistics I just think that this particular metric is misguiding the consumer the average value is just a metric and people give it the wrong context e.g the average american has 2 children, that doesnt mean that having 2 children is what you should personally aim for if you are an american and want to have a happy family.

Comment: @NicolBolas Or maybe I give a more relevant example assume a 10 second game session one GPU renders 30frames every second and will average to 30 FPS an other renders 10frames every second but not in the 9th second in the 9th second it bumps up to 400 frames which make it average 49FPS.. just by looking the average you would have concluded that the second GPU is better... but 10FPS in game is a horrible experience and you would feel that for the most part (9 seconds out of 10) while the other card would have provided you with a much more pleasant experience

Comment: @krOoze Thank you m8 I just saw the question initially, I tinkered a few seconds with OCAT and its excellent for what I need saves the frametimes in excel now the only thing I need is to get only the frame times out of the strings in the excel cells any ideas on the easier way to do that?

Comment: @papajo Excel macros. Or you can try the PresentMon I suggested above; it outputs CSV, which should be straightforward to process.

Answer (score 3):

It is generally what the Vulkan Layer system is for, which allows to intercept API commands and inject your own. But it is nontrivial to code it yourself. Here are some pre-existing open-source options for you:

To get to timing info and draw your custom overlay you can use (and modify) a tool like [OCAT](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/OCAT). It supports Direct3D 11, Direct3D 12, and Vulkan apps.

To just get the timing (and other interesting info) as CSV you can use a command-line tool like [PresentMon](https://github.com/GameTechDev/PresentMon). Should work in D3D, and I have been using it with Vulkan apps too and it seems to accept them.